# Need to pick duplicates based on current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have sample data

```
Name    Product Prd_cnt Prd_dt
BSA     CYCLE   20      29-01-2019
BSA     CYCLE   20      28-01-2019
BSA     CYCLE   20      27-01-2019
BSA     CYCLE   20      26-01-2019
BSA     CYCLE   40      25-01-2019
BSA     CYCLE   35      24-01-2019
BSA     CYCLE   35      23-01-2019
BSA     CYCLE   35      22-01-2019
```

I need to pick the records which have same count for the last 4 days even if the dates are different. From current date to last 4 days. If one of the record is different from the last 4 days. No need of those records.

Output:

```
Name  Product   Prd_cnt   Prd_dt
BSA   CYCLE     20        29-01-2019
BSA   CYCLE     20        28-01-2019
BSA   CYCLE     20        27-01-2019
BSA   CYCLE     20        26-01-2019
```

I have tried using `ROW_NUMBER` and having `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use `exists`.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Name   VARCHAR(50),
  Product VARCHAR(50),
  Prd_cnt INT,
  Prd_dt  DATE
);

INSERT INTO T (Name, Product, Prd_cnt, Prd_dt) VALUES 
('BSA','CYCLE',20,'2019-01-29'),
('BSA','CYCLE',20,'2019-01-28'),
('BSA','CYCLE',20,'2019-01-27'),
('BSA','CYCLE',20,'2019-01-26'),
('BSA','CYCLE',40,'2019-01-25'),
('BSA','CYCLE',35,'2019-01-24'),
('BSA','CYCLE',35,'2019-01-23'),
('BSA','CYCLE',35,'2019-01-22'),
('BSA','CYCLE',40,'2019-01-21');
```

Then, a simple common table expression and an exists subquery:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Name,Product,Prd_cnt,Prd_dt
    FROM T As t0
    WHERE Prd_dt <= GETDATE()
    AND Prd_dt >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()) As Date)
)
SELECT Name,Product,Prd_cnt,Prd_dt
FROM CTE As t0
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM CTE As t1
    WHERE t0.Prd_dt <> t1.Prd_dt
    AND t0.Prd_cnt = t1.Prd_cnt
)
```

The common table expression selects all the records for the last four days, and the exists filters only records that have duplicate Prd_cnt values.
Please note that if you want the duplicate to consider other columns as well, all you have to do is add them to the exists subquery where clause.

Thanks to D-Shih for creating a fiddle for the DDL+DML sample data.

Comment: let me implement this one in my code and get back to you

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use `BETWEEN` and `DATEADD()` to find last 4 days results :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE PRD_DT BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-3,GETDATE()) AS DATE) 
                AND  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT distinct Orders.*
FROM (
    SELECT Name, Product, Prd_cnt, ROW_NUMBER ()   
    OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Product, Prd_cnt order by Prd_dt)  as RN 
    FROM Orders 
)t 
inner join Orders on t.Name = Orders.Name and t.Prd_cnt = Orders.Prd_cnt
and t.Product = Orders.Product where RN >= 4 AND Orders.Prd_dt < GetDate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
select * from myTable t1
where Prd_dt > cast(dateadd(day, -4, getdate()) as date)
and exists(select 1 from myTable
           where Prd_dt > cast(dateadd(day, -4, getdate()) as date)
           and product = t1.product
           group by product
           having count(*) > 1)
```

Subquery will return rows, if for particular `Product` there are more than two records, which in turn will yield you all rows, which have `Product` value repeated in last four days.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE Prd_cnt=(SELECT Prd_cnt FROM T HAVING COUNT(Prd_cnt)>1) and 
DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,(
SELECT Prd_dt FROM T WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,Prd_dt)<4 ORDER BY Prd_dt LIMIT 1));
```